# How can I add birthdays with automatic age to Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

Is there any way to add a birthday to my Google Calendar in such a way that the age is updated automatically?

For instance, if I was born on May 2nd, 1980, then I'd like the entry for 2011 to say, "Nathan's 31st birthday", and for 2012 to say, "Nathan's 32nd birthday", and so on.

Can this be done?

Comment: not an answer but the wish for one!
the 1st above tip starts with "populate your contacts" very nice but what does it mean? then "open Calendar" on the left pan click on "Add" My G calendar left pan does not have a "add" so no "interesting calendar to browse" ... However I found it under "Other Calendar's" dropdown list
Next problem under "Browsing Interest...." then "more" tab I did not see "Contact" or "Birthday and Events"? so could not subscribe to it!
Before doing all this, although unsure of the meaning as stated, I went to my gmail contacts and filled in the birthdate field...But to no

Comment: I know this is quite old, but I recently created a Google Apps Script to add the age to my birthdays. The problem is that you need to distinguish the birthday events in a 'normal' calendar (not the one from contacts), I went with a separate calendar with only birthdays in it. Have a look here: https://gist.github.com/bene-we/e0a306ad6788fec5dbe45cde2de2f140

Answer (score 4):

You can do this but you first need to populate the Birthday field in your contacts.

After you have done this, go to Google Calendar:

- In the left hand pane click `Add` > `Browse Interesting Calendars`
- Click the `More` tab
- Select `Contacts' birthdays and events`
- Click `Subscribe`
- Click `Back to Calendar`

IIRC, the Google Calendar doesn't provide notifications for these events.

To receive notifications you will probably have to use a Third Party Application - one of these Apps being http://contact-birthdays.appspot.com/ ( I haven't used this application I found it via a Google search)

EDIT:

Sorry I missed probably the most important part of the question - I am pretty sure you can't display the age.  This feature request has been outstanding for quite some time now.  There is [this userscript](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/67210) that adds the age to the event.

Comment: This does in fact add birthdays, but it doesn't show the age.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have to turn to a third party website if you'd like to do this without importing from your Google contacts.

Looks like this website may do what you're looking for: http://birthdayfeed.subtlecoolness.com/

Answer (score 0):

The problem with linking it to Google contacts is that I have to add my two-year-old nephew to my contacts for his birthday reminder to appear in my calendar automatically each year (showing his age). It's arguably more important that I remember kids ages than adults, so that makes it irritatingly difficult, given most kids under 12 don't have their own contact information to be listed in my contacts separately to their parents. This really is a function Google should have built into their Calendar by now.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an age from your "Google Calendar" using "Google Assistant" / "Google Home"... But it is NOT straight-forward.

I discovered a work-around.

Let's say you want to ask it for your child's age... It will respond saying it does not know their birth year... (Even if they're an adult)... (Even though you include their birth year in their Contact and Calendar info)...

Step 1. Create Contact... Include name and birthdate. May also include birth year and relationship.

Step 2. Add contact birthdate to google Calendar... From contact.

Step 3. Create a Google Assistant Routine.

Add Commands:

```
                            Example:

                            What's my daughter's age
```

Add action:

```
                           <Name>'s birth year <year>
```

So if your daughter's name is Jane Doe
& if her birthday is January 1st 2012

Your Add Action would be

```
                           Jane's birth year 2012
```

Step 4. Save this routine.

Now from google assistant... Which is on android devices or google home app or google nest mini... Etc.

When you say, "ok google What's my daughter's age"

It will connect the birth day from the Calendar (i.e. Jan 1st) with the birth year from the routine (i.e. 2012)... And it will respond (in the year 2020)  saying,

"January 1st, 2012

Age 8 years"

Or in the year 2021:

"January 1st, 2012

Age 9 years"

Etc.